# Why doesn't Chrome's console display the function code anymore?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the past, if I had a function `test` with the content

```
function test () {
    return true;
}
```

and I typed `test` into console, then I'd get back:

```
function () {
    return true;
}
```

Now however, it just returns `function test()` without the actual function code. How do I change it back to how it was (or at least get the function code)?

Comment: Consoles behave however their programmers make them behave. I doubt you can get it back but I do see you can click the function name and it'll take you to its definition.

Comment: *"Now however, it just returns function test() without the actual function code."* But now it's a link that takes you to the actual function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature was replaced by links to the sections of code where the function was defined. If you follow the link, you can still get to the method definition, just with more context. If you'd like to see the full method definition, try calling toString on it, or just coercing it into a string with addition.

```
function test() { return true; }
test.toString(); //=> "function test() { return true; }"
test + ''; //=> "function test() { return true; }"
```

Chrome DevTools is open source and has [an issues page where you can submit feature requests](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=Cr%3DPlatform-DevTools&sort=&groupby=&colspec=ID+M+Cr+Status+Owner+Summary+Modified+Stars). If you'd like the option to turn on the old behavior, post an issue there.

Answer (score 0):

The new behavior has since been modified for this.

Now the first few lines of the function are shown. So short functions will just display like they used to. However, longer functions are truncated with the link back to the source for context.